# Drag/Drop components are not visible in preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am a beginner in android development. I have created a android project. But in the preview section, I am not able to see the components. [image] But components are visible when i run the same app on emulator i am able to see the components. I am missing some setting here? XML is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: on the top left corner in the "Files" options click on "invalidate Caches/ Restart" and click on "invalidate and restart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had have also this problem and solved it by only selecting another "Theme" cause
the default theme appTheme doesn't show added items. 
If you i.e. select Transulcent, any item becomes visible ;-)

cheers
Oliwan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sound a weird answer, but self-tested this.

- Change the XML file's (maybe activity_x.xml) layout's root tag `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout`, then preview will start working again (as happened in my case). *[If not, then perform force refresh (R)]*
- Then switch back to old one, I mean: Change the XML file's (maybe activity_x.xml) layout's root tag `LinearLayout` to `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`. And force a refresh.

Comment: Maybe some weird indexing/caching problem in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a bug in Android Studio. When it showed up for me, I fixed it by making a trivial change in the app `build.gradle` (change version code), do a gradle sync, then change back and sync again.

After that, the design view worked again.