# Layout Preview is Blank, App Runs Fine

Tags: android, android-layout

Layout Preview is Blank, App Runs Fine.

I see my buttons when I run my app on a device, but the preview layout in Android Studio is blank.

I tried:
-changing the API level.
-restarting Android Studio.
-changing the theme.
-force refreshing layout.
-closing and re-opening activity_main.xml
-switching from design to text and back again
-cleaning the project, then building again

I get can get a loading circle in the corner of layout, but my buttons and textviews do not appear in the layout preview.

Any suggestions?
Is this just an issue of computer performance?

[Here is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAqBE.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566732/ui-editer-not-showing-anything-when-i-drag-on-dop-items-on-it-but-the-code-gets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471760/drag-drop-components-are-not-visible-in-preview-in-android-studio/). This seems to be a recent bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chenge build.gradle dependencies from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

into

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'`

replace all the dependencies contains `28.0.0-alpha3` into `28.0.0-alpha1`.
And then do a gradle sync.
The latest support dependency is not view friendly yet!

Comment: You can post the `build.gradle` if the problem exists.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you very much!