# Layout is just blank?

Tags: android

I have restarted Android Studio, I have invalidated caches, I have Synced many times.. Nothing seems to work at all. Is there a problem with my Theme or my SDK?

It still shows blank on my preview. I am on Android 3.2.0-beta04 and my gradle version is 4.6. Please tell me if I need to add more code or information to this question.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.NAME.calculatorv2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

[image]

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightPureBlue">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/base"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/pureBlue">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@+string/four"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@+string/five"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@+string/six"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subtract"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@+string/subtract"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/pureBlue">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/one"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/two"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/three"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/mul"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/mul"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/pureBlue">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/zero"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/zero"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/clear"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/equal"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/div"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@+string/div"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@+string/seven"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@+string/eight"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@+string/nine"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@+string/add"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is having your layout height and width everywhere is on purpose?

Comment: If your layout was working before, and looks fine on the emulator this could be an issue a lot of people have been reporting lately. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566732/ui-editer-not-showing-anything-when-i-drag-on-dop-items-on-it-but-the-code-gets), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577290/layout-preview-is-blank-app-runs-fine), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471760/drag-drop-components-are-not-visible-in-preview-in-android-studio/). Seems to be a recent bug and it sounds like you've tried most of the posted solutions already...

Comment: @unkgd That's how it was showing how to do it in my classes video

Comment: And as @TylerV mentioned, does it appear correctly on the device itself? Or is it broken in both? If I’m both, try swapping the 0dp with wrap_contant or match_parent. 0dp is usually used for ConstraintLayout to have the view match the constraint rather than a fixed size

Comment: Can you share your manifest and style.xml to let us trace it?

Comment: @unkgd Using 0dp works similarly in LinearLayout, in conjunction with the weight argument (and provided it is on the right dimension - height for a vertical layout or width for a horizontal one)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar problem. What helped me was changing the app theme. In your case it seems to be "NoActionBar". Try changing it to *Material* or *Light*.

Here is an animation of the procedure [image: animated gif]