# Controls are not visible in the .xml file of android studio ,Inspite of adding them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My problem is that when I add controls(like checkbox, buttons) in my constraint layout, they  are not visible on my screen
 You can see I have inserted many controls but none of them are visible also there is no error in my .xml file[Here is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxKuT.png)

Comment: if you have created correct design then it will be displayed. try with cleaning project. if there is problem in xml file then you need to provide the xml file.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle(Module:app)?

Comment: If your layout looks fine on the emulator this could be an issue a lot of people have been reporting lately. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566732/ui-editer-not-showing-anything-when-i-drag-on-dop-items-on-it-but-the-code-gets),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583807/layout-is-just-blank),  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577290/layout-preview-is-blank-app-runs-fine), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471760/drag-drop-components-are-not-visible-in-preview-in-android-studio/). Seems to be a recent bug... Try some of those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First check for this dependency in your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

if you didn't find it, add it to your file and if you did find it, there must be a mistake in your xml.

Try creating a new layout file, findíng the mistake or changing your layout to a relative layout for testing purposes.

Aswell you could try to clean your project (Build --> Clean Project) or rebuild it (Build --> Rebuild Project)

Hopefully something helps! :)

Comment: This dependency is present in my build gradle ,i ebven tried cleaning the project but nothing worked

Comment: And you have created a new layout file? And what happens if start the app (pls attach a picture)